# Facebook Marketing API add AdUser issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Previously, when I work with Facebook Marketing API v2.12, I used this method for adding my user to Ad Account https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/aduser/v2.12 .
Something like in this article https://rdrr.io/cran/rfacebookstat/man/fbUpdateAdAccountUsers.html

Now, In API v3 and higher this method is not available.

As I understand I should change my code to make those methods work:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/assigned_users/v3.3

This is too complex.

Maybe someone knows an easier way to add my user to Ad Account ?